# Distribution of average of two chi squared random variables

Tags: probability

Let X, Y ~ $\chi_1^2$ random variables. What is the distribution of the average? ie, the distribution of $Z = \frac{X+Y}{1}$?

**Correct answer: gamma(a=1, b=1)**

My attempt:

Let $Z = \frac{X+Y}{2}$. Since X, Y are independent chi square R.V, $X+Y = \chi_{2}^2$, so $Z = \frac{\chi_2^2}{2}$

We know that $\chi_n^2$ ~ gamma(a=n/2, b=2), where b is the scale parameter. Writing out the gamma pdf, we have $f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1)2^1}z^{0} exp({\frac{-z}{2}}) \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}exp(\frac{-z}{2}) \neq exp(-z) $ = gamma(a=1, b=1) pdf?

Comment: Why do you think dividing the pdf of $X+Y$ by $2$ gives the pdf of $(X+Y)/2$?

Comment: yeah you're right, I forgot about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$W=X+Y \sim \chi_{(2)}^{2}=\Gamma(2/2 ,2)=\Gamma(1 ,2)$$

now  $Z=\frac{X+Y}{2}=\frac{W}{2}$  so $W=2Z$

$$f_Z(z)=|\frac{d}{dz} 2z| f_W(2z)=2 \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{2z}{2}}$$

Comment: so my mistake was in simply taking the 1/2 outside and multiplying to pdf of X+Y, which is invalid. thank you.

Comment: your mistake was in changing variable method. you are welcome.

Comment: mind answering my other question in the meantime? more chi squaredd :)